# dynamic multi select options in safecracker form

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, safecracker-registration

I am going to be using a safecracker form with zoo-visitor to create membership profiles.

I want to have a field where you choose 1,2,or 3 and if you choose 1 the next field gives you options in a multi select list for 1a if you choose 2, you choose from a list 2a and so on.

Is there anything built in I could use or does it require some custom ajax or is a multi page form the best option?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything built in, but not too long ago John Henry Donovan did a little write-up on implementing something similar with jquery plugins that might help you.

http://johnhenry.ie/articles/chained-selects-for-expressionengine

Comment: You can do just about anything with jQuery so starting there is a very good idea.

Comment: That is a great example.  Only issue I am having it is based on a selection process: Select Category > Display entries from that category.

I need Select Category > Display a second List of Categories.

something like a list of countries > and then a list of states in that country.